# Visual Studio 2012 - How to add animated GIF as Resource for usage with Direct2d

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, resources, animated-gif, direct2d

I've written a class which is able to display an animated GIF file with Direct2D.

Right now I'm accessing the desired GIF to display via it's FilePath like:

```
WCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH] = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\xxx.gif";

m_pIWICFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(  //My IWICImagingFactory
        szFileName,                         
        nullptr,           
        GENERIC_READ, 
        WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad,
        &m_pDecoder);                       //My IWICBitmapDecoder
```

I need to change this part so that the desired GIF will be loaded from the Resources of my Project.

What I did/tried so far:

**1)** 
- I right clicked on My Project, clicked add "Resource" 
- In the popup I've selected "Import" and as Resource Type I defined "GIF"

> Which resulted in a non-buildable project cause of [Error RC2135 in C++ project due to UTF-8 encoding of RC file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244065/error-rc2135-in-c-project-due-to-utf-8-encoding-of-rc-file) 
>   
>  Additionally it "destroyed" my GIF file. Opening the GIF in Notepad showed that it got converted from GIF89a to BM6(.bmp) during this process

**2)** 
- I right clicked on My Project, clicked add "Exsisting Item" and selected my GIF 
- Then i tried to add the give to the .rc file like IDR_MYGIF GIF ".\resources\xxx.gif"

> Which results in "error RC2135: file not found: .\resources\xxx.gif
>   "

So basically I need to know how I can add the GIF correctly to the Resources and how I'll be able to access it in the Code for the IWICBitmapDecoder

Thank you for any help

Comment: Note: In "2)" I tried various paths resulting in the same error

Comment: CreateDecoder *From Filename* does exactly what it promises.  Use CreateDecoderFromStream() instead.  CreateStreamOnHGlobal() is a simple way to obtain the IStream you need.

Comment: @HansPassant If you'd provide a short desc of how to add the GIF to the Resources and then how to make use of it i could mark it as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working... here is what you have to do:

**1) Add your Resource to the project**

> Right Click on the Project - Add - Existing Item - Select your file

**2) Edit your resource.h file**

> Define a identifier for your resource, e.g.: #define IDR_GIF 107

**3) Edit your .rc file**

> IDR_GIF RCDATA "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx.gif"

**4) Define a Stream Pointer**

> I created a private member in my class, e.g.: `LPSTREAM pStream;`

**5) include Shlwapi.dll**

> Add `#include <Shlwapi.h>`

**6) link Shlwapi.lib**

> Project - "Your Project" Properties - Configuration Properties - Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies - Edit - Add Shlwapi.lib

**7) Use the resource**

```
HRSRC myResource = ::FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_GIF), RT_RCDATA);
HGLOBAL myResourceData = ::LoadResource(NULL, myResource);
unsigned int myResourceSize = ::SizeofResource(NULL, myResource);

pStream = SHCreateMemStream((LPBYTE)LockResource(myResourceData), myResourceSize);

m_pIWICFactory->CreateDecoderFromStream(
        pStream,
        nullptr,
        WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad,
        &m_pDecoder);
```

Comment: `pStream` should either be an `IStream*`, or some smart pointer type. Since we cannot see the code after `CreateDecoderFromStream`, there's no way to know for sure, whether the stream object is properly released (by calling `Release`).